# Issues working on SailsJS WebSocket

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm getting response in

```
io.socket.on('chats', function (e, v) {
    console.log(e)
});
```

when using the code block bellow.

```
io.socket.get('/chats', function (e, s) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

So, main setup are okay. Then I tried to customize a bit. I wanted to pass room id to get messages from specific room instead of fetching unnecessary messages. But no response on new item addition when using

```
io.socket.get('/chats/get?room=PJ1RcnwbBxsH3xZn', function (e, s) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

However that was able to fetch initial data properly as used `return res.json(chats);` in ChatsController.get

**From ChatControllers.js**

```
module.exports = {

    get: function (req, res) {

        if(!req.session.authenticated){
            return res.json({error: true, message: 'You must be logged in to join chat.'})
        }

        if (!req.isSocket) {
            return res.json({error: true, message: 'Inappropriate request format'})
        }

        sails.log(req.param('room'));
        if(!req.param('room')){
            return res.json({error: true, message: 'Inappropriate room ID'})
        }

        Chats.find({room: req.param('room')}).populate('user').exec(function (err, chats) {

            if (err) {
                return res.serverError(err);
            }

            Chats.subscribe(req, _.pluck(chats, 'id'));

            return res.json(chats);

        });
    },
.....
```

I've added `Chats.subscribe(req, _.pluck(chats, 'id'));` to subscribe. 
Cannot understand what I've missed in `get` action. I searched but didn't get good tutorial. So exploring documentation, I tried those. Can you advice to fix the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution after more research. **sails.sockets.join()** and **sails.sockets.broadcast()** was my toy.

Thanks however.